# form_error array not working

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I'm doing an error validation in my form, but for some reason validating on each input boxes and displaying it under doesn't work! but for the `validation_errors()` it does work. But I wanted to use `form_error` more. Can you help me?

This is my set_rules placed at my controller:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules("sections", "Section", "trim|required");              
$this->form_validation->set_rules('grade_name', 'Grade name', 'trim|required');         
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div style="color:red;">', '</div>');
```

and this is how I do it on view:

```
$grade_name = array(
    'name'          => 'grade_name',
    'id'            => 'grade_name',
    'value'         => set_value('grade_name'),
    'maxlength'     => '100',
    'size'          => '50',
    'style'         => 'width:100%',
    'class'         => 'form-control m-input m-input--air',          
);

echo form_label('Grade:', 'grade_name');
echo form_input($grade_name);
echo form_error($grade_name);
```

AND IT DOESN'T WORK! :( Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution for your problem :

**Controller.php**

```
<?php 
public function add() {
    $this->template->load('view_file_name');
}
public function save() {
        $data = array();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("sections", "Section", "trim|required");              
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('grade_name', 'Grade name', 'trim|required');         
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div style="color:red;">', '</div>');
        if($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $this->db->trans_begin();
            // Add Here your save code or other stuff
            if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
                flash_data(array('message_type'=>'error','message'=>lang('error')));
                $this->db->trans_rollback();
            } else {
                flash_data(array('message_type'=>'success','message'=>lang('success')));
                $this->db->trans_commit();
                redirect('redirect_page');
            }            
        } else {
            $this->template->load('view_file_name',(!empty($data))?$data:NULL);
        }
    }
?>
```

**view_file_name.php**

```
<?php 
    echo form_open('controller/save',array('id'=>'add_form'));
    $grade_name = array(
        'name'          => 'grade_name',
        'id'            => 'grade_name',
        'value'         => set_value('grade_name'),
        'maxlength'     => '100',
        'size'          => '50',
        'style'         => 'width:100%',
        'class'         => 'form-control m-input m-input--air',          
    );

    echo form_label('Grade:', 'grade_name');
    echo form_input($grade_name);
    echo form_error('grade_name');  

    echo form_button('add',lang('save')); 

    echo form_close(); 
?>
```

I hope it will helps.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work for me too... you see, something's really wrong in my code. I can't find it, only the form_error() doesn't work in my controller but when I'm using it to the other controllers it does! do  you know or might know where this problem coming?

Comment: Please load library form validation in your present controller. `$this->load->library('form_validation');`

Comment: I did, I place it in my public function __construct(){

Answer (score 0):

In `form_error()` you're passing an array. Just add the name of the input

```
echo form_error('grade_name');
```

`'name' => 'grade_name',` name field should comes there

**And set `type` of field**

```
$grade_name = array(
    'name'          => 'grade_name',
    'type'          => 'text', # add this
    'id'            => 'grade_name',
    'value'         => 'grade_name', # remove set_value() from here
    'maxlength'     => '100',
    'size'          => '50',
    'style'         => 'width:100%',
    'class'         => 'form-control m-input m-input--air',          
);
```

---

Read more about [Showing Errors Individually in CodeIgniter.com](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#showing-errors-individually)

Comment: @DeadManAlive: please edit grade_name') and add comma.

Comment: I'm really not sure why it's not working, I have form_validation library and helpers too...

Comment: no way. you're there is something wrong with validation then. check this https://www.formget.com/form-validation-using-codeigniter/

Comment: @NikuNjRathod what error message? nothing is showing so there's no error message, for some-what reason forrm_error() doesn;t work. :(

Comment: did you check that tutorial? that's working fine without any issue

Comment: I did, I took time redoing my code but still doesn't work.,